# Why were block closures excluded in java?

Tags: java, closures, block

I am a mainstream java programmer but recently, I've been taking interest in smalltalk. I must admit that I am totally blown by the immense power that the language gives to the programmer and I find dynamic typing as a big plus (personally).

I do not want to compare the two languages because I understand that java is a good fit for the enterprise reality that takes away much of the programmer's power for good (like the usage of pointers?) to lessen the scope for committing mistakes. Agreed. But I fail to understand why was the concept of blocks/closures <strike>eliminated</strike> not included in the language? Because I really find them very useful and I don't see a reason why such powerful a feature cannot be married into java, albeit the fact that it is static typed. Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: Features aren't generally *removed* from languages - they're just not *included*, which is a big difference. Lambda expressions will hopefully make it into Java 8...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it was not included because Java has based on languages which did not have this feature.  Instead Java has alternatives which achieve the same thing but in relatively ugly ways.

Hopefully, it will be included in Java 8 if only to stop people complaining about it. ;)

> I don't see a reason why such powerful a feature cannot be married into java

Can you think of a realistic example of something you can do with a closure, you can't do with Java already?  The main difference is productivity and readability. While these are very important, its not like it can't be done.

Comment: That's not a good argument. Everything you can do in Java you can do in machine code, but we don't want to have to. Productivity and readability are the *only* things that are important, that's what a programming language *is*. See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProgrammingLanguagesAreSyntacticSugar

Comment: That doesn't mean you add every possible feature of every language.  Most languages which attempt to do this die of to be replaced with simpler languages.  Java errs on the side of being feature poor, but at least you have a good chance of understanding them all.  While closures are cool, there is still not agreement as to the design for Java 8 even though other languages have supported it for some time. i.e. the idea isn't as mature as you might expect.